# How to update session entity in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have defined an entity named visible_objects in my Dialogflow agent.

In the Dialogflow console I have put one entry named placeholder2 with a synonym placeholder.

[image]

When a user starts interacting with the agent, I'm updating this entity via the projects.agent.sessions.entity patch request.  Following is the content of the request I'm sending.

```
`{
    "name": "projects\/{PROJECT_NAME}\/agent\/sessions\/{SESSION}\/entityTypes\/visible_objects",
    "entityOverrideMode": "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE",
    "entities": [
        {
            "value": "door",
            "synonyms": [
                "door"
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "desk",
            "synonyms": [
                "desk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "value": "test tubes",
            "synonyms": [
                "test tubes",
                "test",
                "tubes"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`
```

And this is the code I'm using to generate it:

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$df_action = $request['queryResult']['action'];
$df_contexts = $request['queryResult']['outputContexts'];
$df_parameters = $request['queryResult']['parameters'];

// taken from private_key in my GCP authentication .json file
$CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxxxxxxxx---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

// loop through the visible objects and prepare the output for dialogflow
foreach($_SESSION['STORY']['VISIBLE_OBJECTS'] as $visible_object)
{
    unset($synonyms);       // clear any existing synonyms
    $synonyms = array();
    $synonyms[] = $visible_object['name'];
    if (strpos($visible_object['name'], ' ', 1))
    {       // multiple words so split it as synonyms
        $sub_objects = explode(' ', $visible_object['name']);
        foreach($sub_objects as $sub_object)
            $synonyms[] = $sub_object;
    }

    // add the object to the user entity
    $user_ent_objects[] = array('value'=>$visible_object['name'], 'synonyms'=>$synonyms);
}

// prepare user_entity
$user_entity = array('name'=>$request['session'] . '/entityTypes/visible_objects', 'entityOverrideMode'=>'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE', 'entities'=>$user_ent_objects);

// log for debugging
file_put_contents($SITE_DIR . '/webhook/user-entity-visible-objects.txt',  json_encode($user_entity,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

$ch = curl_init('https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/' . $request['session'] . '/entityTypes/visible_objects');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);        // tell it we're posting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN));      // set the headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($user_entity));     // load our data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);     // execute it

?>
```

I have an intent which is "look on the object name", where object name is mapped to the visible_objects entity.  Here's what I'm seeing for some example phrases:

- look on the placeholder -> "placeholder" is detected as object name
- look on the test -> no object name detected
- look on the tubes -> no object name detected
- look on the desk -> no object name detected

Based on these responses is appears the session entity is not being updated as the new values are not detected and similarly the old value placeholder2 is not overwritten.

My webhook is written in PHP, and I'm not using the Google SDK (it is only in alpha for PHP).  I am capturing the response from the [request curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) but nothing is being returned.

Using curl_getinfo I'm seeing the following:

```
`[url] => https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/escaperoom-447aa/agent/sessions/SESSION_ID_MASKED/entityTypes/visible_objects
[content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 400
[header_size] => 144
[request_size] => 2002
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.072034
[namelookup_time] => 0.023728
[connect_time] => 0.031063
[pretransfer_time] => 0.065598
[size_upload] => 394
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 5472
[download_content_length] => 1555
[upload_content_length] => 394
[starttransfer_time] => 0.065659
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 216.58.192.234
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => 66.198.240.46
[local_port] => 41442
```

`

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you update the question to show the code you're using to do the update?

Comment: Sure @Prisoner, I've updated the question with my PHP code. Let me know if there's anything else you need. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where is the code that sets `$request` to something, and what does that code look like?

Comment: request is populated with the data coming from DialogFlow. I've updated the code sample above to include this piece of my webhook.

Comment: And you say that *nothing* is returned? Can you update your question with the results from `curl_getinfo( $ch )` after the exec?

Comment: I was using capturing the response in $curl_response and then logging the value of $curl_response.  I've now logged curl_getinfo and added it to my question.  It's returning a 400 error.

I've seen your answer to my question below. I will need to work through that later this week and will let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're not setting `$CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN` to an access token. You're setting it to your private key which should be associated with a service account.

You will need to use that private key to [generate an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) - it is not the access token itself. Since there is a service definition for the Dialogflow service, you can choose to just [generate a signed JWT for the service](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#jwt-auth).